# What is a MV* framework?

Tags: design-patterns

I heard and read the term MV* Framework a lot lately. I guess it stands for Model-View-* Framework. But how does it differ from MVC Frameworks and how is the * to be explained?

Comment: There are many variations of this type of framework including MVC (Model-View-Controller), MVP (Model-View-Presenter), MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), MVCVM (Model-View-Controller-ViewModel). I will leave more detailed answer to someone who has a better understanding though :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're referring to any framework that implements one of the many MV* (as in, model-view-wildcard) design patterns. There's MVC (model-view-controller), MVVM (model-view-view model), MVP (model-view-presenter), and probably some more.

The * is just a wildcard, not something specific.

Read up on it here: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/nanil/archive/2013/04/01/exploring-javascript-mv-frameworks-part-1-hello-backbonejs.aspx

Comment: And with any of the JS-MV*-Frameworks I can implement every MV* Pattern? Are these just slightly different concepts than the MVC Pattern? I am pretty new to all that, just getting my head around Ruby on Rails but I am also interested in JS since I need to use it for my Rails Project as well. I want to figure out which frameworks / technologies I need, to do with just JS what I do with Rails now. And what other options there are, as for example different design patterns. As in the question, I don't understand why this answer gets a -1 ?

Comment: For MV*, personally I've found it's rare for anyone to perfectly implement the academic definition of an MVC pattern. There's almost always at least a bit of MVVM (where the VM is responsible for data-binding) and/or MVP (where the 'presenter' has the logic to apply user events in the view as updates to the model, or events on the model as updates to the view). For MV*, the model will manage your data and application logic, and the view defines how that will be 'viewed' (eg the html, xml, json, csv, excel spreadsheet, PDF, etc.) The * can be any number of ways the M and V will play together.

Comment: What this answer is missing is a rationale how/why an MV* framework could have added value to websites--as opposed to plain javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 8):

MV* is Model-View-Whatever architecture. The term is being used in AngularJS, where the Model represents (Data) any variable from javascript or something, View represents HTML side, and * i.e whatever represents whatever that binds these two together.

Comment: The "whatever that binds these two together" part of the sentence is pretty enlightening.